# Storage in a variable of the options chosen in an HTML form

Tags: php, html

My question is this: I have an HTML form in which the user can select several options. I would like to retrieve all these choices and store them one after the other in a variable, separated by a comma.

I realized this:

> form.html

```
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="motif" name="motif[]" required>
        <option>Meurtre au premier degré</option>
        <option>Meurtre au premier degré avec circ. aggr.</option>
        <option>Dissimulation de preuve</option>
        <option>Fraude</option>
    </select>
```

> result.php

```
foreach ($_POST["motif"] as $valeur) {
    $selecteditem = $selecteditem+$valeur;
}
echo $selecteditem;
```

> output 'echo $selecteditem'

```
0
```

I don't understand this "0", I would like a result like: "Corruption, Armed robbery, Illegal carrying of weapons" at the output of the variable $selecteditem

Thank you for your expert advice :)

Comment: In PHP, if you want to join two strings together, you use the dot `.` operator, not plus `+`. Try with `$selecteditem = $selecteditem.$valeur;` instead. You might even want to add a space and a comma... `$selecteditem = $selecteditem.", ".$valeur;` . See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php. `+` is an arithmetic operator (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: Thanks you !!! It's works!!

Answer (score 1):

Add values to your options, so make it:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="motif" name="motif[]" required>
    <option value='degre'>Meurtre au premier degré</option>
    <option value='circ'>Meurtre au premier degré avec circ. aggr.</option>
    <option value='preuve'>Dissimulation de preuve</option>
    <option value='fraude'>Fraude</option>
</select>
```

Then change your php to:

```
$selectedItems = join(', ', $_POST["motif"]);
```

This will take the array and join it using comma as the glue.

Comment: "because there are no values in your options"...this part isn't true. If there is no "value" attribute for an option, the browser will send the text instead

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I removed that bit from my answer